# Weird networking issue under 12.04

Tags: networking, command-line, proxy

I am having problems with networking in the command line, specifically with the gem installer (I had similar issues yesterday but can't remember exactly what with).

So, I am getting:

```
pete@pete-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo gem install bundler
[sudo] password for pete: 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/gems/bundler-1.1.3.gem)
```

Next, I can't ping external addresses:

```
pete@pete-Latitude-E6510:~$ ping -c 3 209.85.231.104
PING 209.85.231.104 (209.85.231.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.8.8.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
```

I am behind a proxy. I can ping the default gateway (I believe it is) on 10.8.8.2 and the proxy on 10.8.8.13 (which runs on a non-standard port).

`apt-get`, for example, works fine from the command line, and all access (browser, update manager, etc) works fine in the GUI.

I have googled extensively but can't get further at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Gem does not respect or know about the systemwide proxy settings. To use a proxy, Gem requires that:

1. The http proxy be specified as an environment variable
2. Gem told to use this proxy via command-line switch or via `.gemrc`

So, in your terminal session, first specify the proxy, assuming it is on port 12345 (change as appropriate): `export HTTP_PROXY=http://10.8.8.13:12345`

and then invoke Gem with the `-p` switch **at the end**: `sudo gem install bundler -p`

To make this persistent, you can set `HTTP_PROXY` in your `.bashrc` (other console programs, including `wget` and `curl` will also use this if it is set) and for gem, add the line `--http-proxy` to `$HOME/.gemrc`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response. But this is just getting weirder by the minute:

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response, @izx. But this is just getting weirder by the minute: 'pete@pete-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo export HTTP_PROXY=http://10.8.8.13:8011
sudo: export: command not found'. But without sudo works fine (but I know it's not the result we want). Then 'pete@pete-Latitude-E6510:~$ sudo sudo gem -p install bundler
ERROR:  Invalid option: -p.  See 'gem --help'.'. Gem version gives 1.8.15, I know this is getting into Linux basics, but what on earth is going on?

Comment: OK. Found the issue in export (needed to run from sudo -s).

Comment: Right. all fixed now. gem command should have been 'gem install bundler -p'. Sorry, don't know how to line break in this commenting system...

Comment: Happy to help. Sorry about the `-p`; I don't use ruby and from the gem man page assumed it would take switches before or after.